# switching at the touch of a button

Tags: javascript

I have the code

```
<div class="answer question_one hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="0" name="happy" value="yes">
    <label for="0"></label>
</div>
<div class="answer question_two hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="0" name="happy" value="yes">
    <label for="0"></label>
</div>
<div class="answer question_three hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="0" name="happy" value="yes">
    <label for="0"></label>
</div>

<button type="button" class="next_button">Next</button>
```

how to implement switching between them sequentially so that when you click on the button, hidden is removed from the questions?

Comment: Please give some context to your question. Where are the "questions"? Please add to your html.

Comment: @Lee Taylor I exaggerated, the whole code does not fit

Comment: The duplicate `id` and `for` attributes make for invalid HTML, and will cause you problems.

Comment: I posted this as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, you can store the "current answer" index in a variable, and then increment it everytime the button gets clicked:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.next_button')

var currAnswer = 1;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  const answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer')
  answers.forEach( function(el, i) {
    if (!el.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      el.classList.add('hidden')
    }
  })
  answers[currAnswer].classList.remove('hidden')
  
  currAnswer++
  if (currAnswer >= answers.length) {
    currAnswer = 0
  } 
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="answer question_one">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="0" name="happy" value="yes">
    <label for="0">0</label>
</div>
<div class="answer question_two hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="1" name="happy" value="yes">
    <label for="1">1</label>
</div>
<div class="answer question_three hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="2" name="happy" value="yes">
    <label for="2">2</label>
</div>

<button type="button" class="next_button">Next</button>
```

Comment: you can hide the previous one

Comment: edited to hide previous answers

Comment: how to make the first question appear immediately without clicking on the button

Comment: edited to show the first question: I removed `hidden` from first question div, and set `currentAnswer = 1`

Comment: and another question is how to check if the user clicked on the checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original edit:

Add a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to each div, and use that in your click handler to determine which div to hide, and which div to show next.

```js
// Cache the elements
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
const button = document.querySelector('.next');

// The handler return a function that is called
// when the click event occurs
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

// Use the id to target the div with that id
// and toggle the hidden class
function toggle(id) {
  const selector = `[data-id="${id}"]`;
  const question = document.querySelector(selector);
  question.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

// Initialise the id to 0
function handleClick(id = 0) {
  return function () {
    
    // If the id is less than the
    // number of questions hide the current div
    // increase the id, then show that div
    if (id < divs.length) {
      if (id > 0) toggle(id);
      ++id;
      toggle(id);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.next { margin-bottom: 1em; }
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="next">Next</button>

<div data-id="1" class="question hidden">Question 1</div>
<div data-id="2" class="question hidden">Question 2</div>
<div data-id="3" class="question hidden">Question 3</div>
<div data-id="4" class="question hidden">Question 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final and clean working code that switches between the divs of your questions to show one at a time. All the best!

CSS goes here:

```
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
```

HTML goes here:

```
 <div class="answer question_one hidden">
   <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-checkbox"
    id="0"
    name="happy"
    value="yes"
   />
  <label for="0">Question 1</label>
</div>
<div class="answer question_two hidden">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-checkbox"
    id="0"
    name="happy"
    value="yes"
  />
  <label for="0">Question 2</label>
</div>
<div class="answer question_three hidden">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-checkbox"
    id="0"
    name="happy"
    value="yes"
  />
  <label for="0">Question 3</label>
</div>
```

JavaScript goes here:

```
// track the next and current element
let nextIndex = 0;
let currentIndex = 0;

// get the button
const btn = document.querySelector(".next_button");
//add click event that fires the nextFunc function below
btn.addEventListener("click", nextFunc);
//get all elements with class hidden
const hidden = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");

// next function
function nextFunc() {
  //increase the next element by 1  and go back to zero if got to an end
  nextIndex++;
  if (nextIndex >= hidden.length) {
    nextIndex = 0;
  }

  //get the next and current element
  const nextElement = hidden[nextIndex];
  const currentElement = hidden[currentIndex];

  //show the next and hide the current
  nextElement.classList.remove("hidden");
  currentElement.classList.add("hidden");

  //increment the current element to be the next element and and reset if above
  currentIndex++;
  if (currentIndex >= hidden.length) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
}

//show the first question at first
hidden[currentIndex].classList.remove("hidden");
```